# Haskell Job Pool

Tags: multithreading, haskell, jobs

I'm interested in Haskell programming, but I'd want to create a job pool system, and I wonder if that will be a problem in Haskell.

Below is a simple program in Ruby.  On one thread of execution, words are taken from a user and added to a list.  On another thread, words are taken from the list and processed in some way (in this case, reversed and printed back to the user).

```
words = []

# Create new thread to take words from array, one at a time, and process them
t = Thread.new {
  loop do
    unless words.empty?
      word = words.pop
      break if word == 'quit'
      sleep 1
      puts word.reverse
    end
  end
}

# Take words from user and add to array
loop do
  puts "Enter word:"
  word = gets.chomp
  words << word
  break if word == 'quit'
end

t.join
```

What is the equivalent Haskell code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pretty close translation.

`Chan` is a FIFO queue for message passing between Haskell threads.

Below I use a `MVar` for waiting that the spooler has exited. This is like a regular mutable variable, but it is protected with a mutex. It can either be empty (only a `put` is allowed, `take`s wait) or full (only a `take` is allowed, `put`s wait).

I also use Haskell threads below, which might be run on separate OS-level threads or not -- the Haskell runtime chooses that. Haskell threads are very cheap, compared with OS threads.

See e.g. [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) for more discussion.

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module JobPool where

import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Concurrent

spooler :: Chan String -> MVar () -> IO ()
spooler ch stop = do
   word <- readChan ch
   if word == "quit"
   then putMVar stop ()
   else do
      threadDelay 1000000 -- us
      putStrLn (reverse word)
      spooler ch stop

main :: IO ()
main = do
   stop <- newEmptyMVar
   ch <- newChan
   _ <- forkIO $ spooler ch stop
   let loop = do
          word <- getLine
          writeChan ch word
          when (word /= "quit") loop
   loop
   takeMVar stop
```

Comment: `forkOS` doesn't give new OS threads.  It's rather poorly named in that sense.  The only difference `forkOS` has from `forkIO` is that it guarantees all FFI calls from the new thread will happen from the same native thread. It says nothing about no other haskell code running on that native thread.

Comment: @chi Thank you. Would it be a straightforward task to instead add the 'spooler' function to the channel together with the word, and then, in the new thread, have a higher-level function that applies the lower-level function ('spooler') to the word?

Comment: @VorpulusLyphane I'm not sure I completely understand, but you can pass IO actions if you make e.g. `Chan (IO ())`. In such way the spooler thread can fetch the action and run it. You can `writeChan ch (do print 1; print 2)` and the numbers will be printed by the spooler thread using something like `do act <- readChan ch ; act`